# Joi array validation: allow empty array

Tags: joi

When using `Joi.array().items(...)` does this require that at least one item be present, even if no type matchers are marked as required?

Comment: No, it doesn't require any item. You can use an empty array. If you want at least one item to be present, you should use `.min(1)`.

Comment: We had a test that failed because we created a new user and the new user did not have any data for this particular field, so an empty array was returned. When we modified the test to not check for item types, the test passed... Not sure why it failed with an empty array using the `.items(...)` function.

Comment: How about this: `Joi.array().min(0).items(Joi.string().min(5).label("item").optional())
`

Answer (score 3):

```
Joi.array().min(1).messages({
    "array.min": "Array can't be empty!"
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
Joi.array().items(...).empty(Joi.array().length(0))
```

Comment: Please add comments to explain your answer beyond a code example so that others can learn why something works.